# Prove by induction that $21^n-21$ is divisible by $5$ for all natural numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, induction

> Prove by induction that $21^n-21$ is divisible by $5$ for all natural numbers.

I have tried this question several times but am always having to use that $0$ is divisible by $5$ in step one

So far I have done;

$21^1-21=0$ which is divisible by 5

then assumed true for n=k

I cannot think of a way to use these steps for n+1

Comment: Please add the steps you have already taken so we can help point out where you may have gone wrong. People will be more willing to answer if you show you have put in some effort first

Comment: $0$ **is divisible** by $5$ ......

Comment: Also, do you mean $21^n-21$ or $21^{n-21}$

Comment: What's wrong with using "zero is divisible by five"?

Comment: The observation you need is that $21^n$ will always have $1$ as its last digit so when you subtract $21$ you get a number that ends in $0$ which must be divisible by $5$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base Case ($n = 1$): $21^1 = 21 = 0$, and $0$ is of course divisible by $5$.

Induction Hypothesis: Assume $21^k - 21$ is divisible by $5$. Hence, there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $21^k - 21 = 5m$. (Hence, $21^k =  21 + 5m$).

Induction Step: We have: 
\begin{align*}
21^{k+1} - 21 & = 21^k \cdot 21 - 21 \\
& = (21 + 5m) 21 - 21 \\
& = 441 + 5(21m) - 21 \\
& = 420 + 5(21m) \\
& = 5(84) + 5(21m) \\
& = 5(84 + 21m).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

$21^{n+1}-21= 21^n \cdot 21-21=(21^n-21) \cdot 21+21^2-21=(21^n-21) \cdot 21+420.$

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can see that $21^{n+1}-21= 21^{n+1}-21^n+21^n-21=21^n(21-1)+(21^n-21)=20\cdot 21^n + (21^n-21)$
Since $21^{n+1}-21$ can be written as Sum of two multiple of 5 you have the inductive step!

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at it, as mentioned in the comments, is that as $21$ ends in a $1$ multiplying it by itself will also result in a number which ends in $1$:

\begin{align}21^2&=441\\
21^3&=9261\\
21^4&=194481\\
&\vdots\end{align}

We then subtract $21$ from this, so the resulting number must end in a $0$ and thus is divisible by $5$, as all multiples of $5$ end in a $0$ or a $5$

Answer (score 0):

Step: $n+1$

$21^{n+1}-21=21(21^n-1)=$

$21((21^n-21)+(21-1))=$

$21(21^n-21)+21\cdot 20$;

Since $(21^n-21)$ is divisible by $5$ (hypothesis), so is the first summand, and so is the second summand $21\cdot 20.$